# ansible, compare variables between keys and avoid action on recurrence

Tags: variables, ansible, compare

I'm trying to write a playbook which consider a value one time only if repeated.
An example would better explain what i mean:

considering the following inventory:

```
[plot]
server1 dir=graph
server2 dir=graph
server3 dir=keller
server4 dir=graph
```

Playbook should copy files to server dir1 (graph), then on server2 should skip the copy. On server3 will copy files, but again on server 4 shouldn't copy any file.
It should evaluate the first server, then save the value to a list and go on. I guess there should be a simpler way because values are not dynamics.

thx in advance

Answer (score 2):

Create a list of unique directories, e.g.

```yaml
        - set_fact:
            dirs_unique: "{{ dict(_hosts|zip(_dirs))|
                             dict2items|
                             groupby('value') }}"
          vars:
            _hosts: "{{ groups.plot }}"
            _dirs:  "{{ groups.plot|map('extract', hostvars, 'dir') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  dirs_unique:
  - - graph
    - - key: server1
        value: graph
      - key: server2
        value: graph
      - key: server4
        value: graph
  - - keller
    - - key: server3
        value: Keller
```

Now select the first host from each item. These will be the hosts to copy files to

```yaml
        - set_fact:
            hosts_unique: "{{ dirs_unique|json_query('[][0].key') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  hosts_unique:
  - server1
  - server3
```

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: plot
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - block:
        - set_fact:
            dirs_unique: "{{ dict(_hosts|zip(_dirs))|
                             dict2items|
                             groupby('value') }}"
          vars:
            _hosts: "{{ groups.plot }}"
            _dirs:  "{{ groups.plot|map('extract', hostvars, 'dir') }}"
        - set_fact:
            hosts_unique: "{{ dirs_unique|json_query('[][0].key') }}"
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        msg: "Copy files to {{ dir }}"
      when: inventory_hostname in hosts_unique
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [server1] => 
  msg: Copy files to graph
skipping: [server2]
ok: [server3] => 
  msg: Copy files to keller
skipping: [server4]
```